# How to save picturebox image into mysql database without imagepath

Tags: c#, mysql

i just wanted to know if it is possible to save images into the database without the image path like for example a default image already assigned into the picture box. This is the sample code that I used that requires an image location.

```
byte[] imageBt = null;
FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.txtImage.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
imageBt = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);

conn.Open();
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("insert into images(image)values(@IMG)", conn);
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@IMG", imageBt));

reader = command.ExecuteReader();
MessageBox.Show("Saved");

while (reader.Read())
{

}
```

Comment: How else do you want to receive the image as? An Image or Bitmap object? Also is the Mysql column in question a Blob column?

Comment: i want to set an image object is a default image set into the picture box and yes the Mysql column is set to Blob.. thank you for noticing my question .. xD

Comment: Yes, it is possible. There is a nice [example video on youTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szIj1xvNfMU), which uses a memorystream that feeds from an PictureBox.Image. But there probably are several posts here too, that show you how, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503154/load-an-image-to-c-sharp-and-then-inserting-into-mysql-table).. Do take a look at the various Blob sizes! [Look here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/how-to-save-images-in-mysql-database-using-C-Sharp/)!! Blob is only 255 byte, by default

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/585099/Howplustoplusstoreplus-plusretrieveplusimagesplu

Comment: Correction: The blob sizes in the link are wrong. Tinyblob<=255, blob<=64k, mediumblob<=16M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MemoryStream` to save image from PictureBox to byte array

```
    Image image = pictureBox.Image;
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);

    byte[] imageBt = memoryStream.ToArray();
```

other parts would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this one...

```
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        byte[] pic_arr = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.Read(pic_arr, 0, pic_arr.Length);

        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into images(image, name)values(@img,@imgName)", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgName", txtName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", pic_arr);
        int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("COmplete");
```